# How do I change the default highlight color in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I found the file for each theme, but I don't know which line to edit.

Comment: This question is about software tool used in programming and as such is not any kind of off topic to StackOverflow as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky I agree. Yet another example of overzealous closing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ctrl+F - `<key>lineHighlight</key>` right the next one after it. If you mean the selection color - `<key>selection</key>`, or if you mean searched text highlight - `<key>findHighlight</key>`

Also note the comment by **Himanshu P** below.

Comment: None of those work for when you double click on a word and it highlights all the the matches. Which key do you edit for that? Can you update your answer?

Comment: On Mac, the .tmTheme files are under `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default/` --p.s. I can't seem to find the "Find All" color setting...

Comment: Add the key <key>selectionForeground</key> as well, otherwise the foreground color won't change on selection, and depending on the syntax highlighting color-rules, sometimes the foreground text might not be visible. Black (#000) might be a good choice for the value of this key, if the selection color is to be a light one.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23714206/3345375