# Sublime Text: Change highlight background

Tags: sublimetext

I would like to change the color on all the found instances (when you use find) of the word that have been found. I noticed that the highlightBackground key just changes the first instance. Is there a way to change the highlight color of all the found instances?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following examples are from the [`Neon Color Scheme`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (full disclosure - I'm its designer):

So I'm searching though my `Package Control.sublime-settings` file trying to find all of my packages with ***`HTML`*** (case-insensitive) in their name. I open up the Find dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on OS X) and type *`HTML`* into the search box, after unchecking the regex, case-sensitive, and whole-word options. The following appears:

[image: Find]

The yellow background behind the first found item on Line 22 is themed using the `findHighlight` setting, while the blue font (foreground) is themed using `findHighlightForeground`. I can hit <kbd>F3</kbd> (Win/Lin, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> on OS X) to scroll through each match.

However, say I want a multi-selection so I can change them all at once. I hit Find All (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on OS X) and the window now looks like so:

[image: Find All]

This is the same coloring used when you manually select text. The bright blue background is themed using the `selection` setting, while the bright green border around it is themed using `selectionBorder`. The text color (foreground) is the same as defined elsewhere in the color scheme for that particular scope. Defining `selectionForeground` doesn't seem to have any effect.

The full `settings` dict for Neon looks like this:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>activeGuide</key>
        <string>#FF0080</string>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#000000</string>
        <key>caret</key>
        <string>#FFFFFF</string>
        <key>findHighlight</key>
        <string>#F2FF06</string>
        <key>findHighlightForeground</key>
        <string>#1515FF</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FFFFFF</string>
        <key>guide</key>
        <string>#6F6F6F</string>
        <key>inactiveSelection</key>
        <string>#353576</string>
        <!-- invisibles doesn't seem to work for me -->
        <key>invisibles</key>
        <string>#06FF05</string>
        <key>lineHighlight</key>
        <string>#2D2D2D</string>
        <key>selection</key>
        <string>#0205FF</string>
        <key>selectionBorder</key>
        <string>#06FF05</string>
        <key>stackGuide</key>
        <string>#06FF05</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: What if i'm in an CSS or HTML scope? It seems to have its own theme settings that override the default. Where do I change that?

Comment: @MattDMo do you know if there is a way to customize the color of not just the first occurrence found (highlighted in yellow in your 1st screenshot) when searching for text, but the rest of them (only the border seems visible)?

Comment: Just answering myself, seems you can add a new key           <key>highlight</key>
          <string>#ffea00</string>